# AudioWorklet returning processed data besides node, how?

Tags: javascript, angular, web-audio-api

I'm trying to return a buffer using an AudioWorklet.
This is what I have so far.

Method in a service:

```
private record(stream: MediaStream): void {
    const audioContext = new AudioContext({sampleRate: 16000});

    audioContext.audioWorklet.addModule('downsample-processor.js').then(() => {
        const src = this.audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
        const node = new AudioWorkletNode(this.audioContext, 'downsample-processor');

        src.connect(node).connect(audioContext.destination);

        // do something w. outputData.buffer from the audio worklet (see processor below)
    }).catch((err) => console.error(err));
}
```

down-sample-processor.js:

```
class DownsampleProcessor extends AudioWorkletProcessor {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    process(inputs, outputs, parameters) {
        const input = inputs[0];
        const sampleRate = 16000;
        const bufferSize = 8192;
        const ratio = input.sampleRate / sampleRate;
        const length = Math.floor(bufferSize / ratio);
        const inputData = input[0];  // float 32 array
        let outputData = new Int16Array(length); // int 16 array
        let curSample, newSample;

        for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            curSample = Math.floor(i * ratio);
            newSample = Math.min(inputData[curSample] * 32768, 32767);
            outputData[i] = Math.floor(newSample);
        }

        // HOW to return ouputData.buffer?

        return true;
    }
}

registerProcessor('downsample-processor', DownSampleProcessor);
```

So how do I return the ouputData.buffer from the processor to the method in the service?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The `outputs` parameter for `process` is where the output of the `AudioWorkletNode` goes.  So copy `outputData` to `outputs[0][0]`.

I also see that when you compute newSample, you clamp values to at most 32767.  That's fine.  But you also need to clamp values below -32768.  Not sure why you're clamping though.  WebAudio works with floats so unless you really want this to reduce the number of bits, you don't need to do this.  Just leave everything as floats, with clamping and with converting to 16-bit accuracy.

Also, your computations seem to assume that you will have `length` number of samples in `inputData`.  This is wrong.  The length of `input[0]` is exactly 128.  You'll have to do a lot more work to get downsampling to work.  Note also, that WebAudio only works at one sampleRate.  If you expect WebAudio to process the output of your worklet as if the sample rate were 16000, then you'll be disappointed.  You should probably send the downsampled audio somewhere else via a MessagePort or SharedArrayBuffer.  (This could actually be another AudioContext whose sampleRate you set to 16000.)

Also `inputs.sampleRate` doesn't exist.  You want to get the `sampleRate` from the `AudioWorkletGlobalScope`.

Comment: Thanks @Raymond! The process is to downsample to 16 bits, 16 kHz. I do clamp values below -32768, because the [Audiobuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBuffer) samples are between -1.0 and 1.0. I just have to get rid of the maximum value. Thanks for tipping me about the `length`!

Comment: The only clamping I see is `newSample = Math.min(inputData[curSample] * 32768, 32767);` and if input is, say, -2, you'll get -65536.   In general AudioBuffers can contain any finite floating-point value, but presumably you're in control of the contents so you can make appropriate assumptions.  Good luck!